# How to convert symbol or string in to proper class name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an class with namespace, and I want to get the name of that class by converting the given string, what is the best way to do it. Below is my class and respective string

```
module Test
 class Myclass
 end 
end
```

I want to get the above class name from the string as like below

```
string = "test_myclass", I want to convert this in to Test::Myclass
```

Also the string is not fixed one, its dynamic for example it needs to convert the below string 
as TestMyclass , if the class "TestMyclass" is exist in rails app

```
 class TestMyclass
 end 

string = "test_myclass", convert this in to TestMyclass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#camelize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize) method to get the class name as string:

```
string = "test_myclass"
string.gsub('_', '/').camelize
# => "Test::Myclass"
```

Then, [`#constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) it:

```
string = "test_myclass"
string.gsub('_', '/').camelize.constantize
# => Test::Myclass
```

For your updated question, you can check if `TestMyclass` exists, using

```
string = "test_myclass"
klass = begin
  # trying TestMyclass, if it doesn't exit
  # this will raise "NameError: uninitialized constant TestMyclass" 
  string.camelize.constantize
rescue NameError
  # if TestMyclass was not found, pick Test::Myclass
  string.gsub('_', '/').camelize.constantize
end
```

Comment: @mudasobwa Don't understand your note. Everything above tested and worked in Rails 4 console.